# css background must be overflow of its parent

Tags: css

I want to background image be overflow from its parent. The solution must be **CSS only**.

**I want:**

[image: i want this]

**but I have:**
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TvWM4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative bottom margin:

```
.mahboobs-link a{
    text-align:left;
    color:#b76c00;
    display:block;
    width:87px;
    height:53px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding-left:10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:11;
    margin-bottom: -21px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/TvWM4/2/